# strugling with formating and identify result

Tags: php, templates, mysqli, twig

I use the following SQL to fetch positions for content.

```
$leftBlock ='l';
$rightBlock ='r';
$topBlock = 'c';
$bottomBlock = 'd';

$blockposition = array();

$result2 = $db->sql_query("SELECT bposition FROM {$prefix}_blocks_manager WHERE module_title ='$name'"); 
while($row2 = $db->sql_fetchrow($result2)) { 
$blockposition[] = $row2['bposition'];

}

$blockposition2 = array_unique($blockposition);//remove duplicates becouse db output can be like:lllrrrd
if (in_array($leftBlock, $blockposition2) AND in_array($rightBlock, $blockposition2)) {
    $mytestresult = "We go use a template with left and right blocks";
}
if (in_array($leftBlock, $blockposition2) AND !in_array($rightBlock, $blockposition2)) {
    $mytestresult = "We go use a template with just left blocks";
}
if (!in_array($leftBlock, $blockposition2) AND in_array($rightBlock, $blockposition2)) {
    $mytestresult = "We go use a template with just right blocks";
}
if (!in_array($leftBlock, $blockposition2) AND !in_array($rightBlock, $blockposition2)) {
    $mytestresult = "We go use a template with just content";
}
```

The `$name` represents the page where I am looking at.

`$mytestresult` will go tell Twig to load the specific template:

`$template = $twig->loadTemplate('mytestresult_file.phtml');`

But for each template above i can create content that adds new content above or below the existing content.

`$topBlock`and `$bottomBlock`

Inside my script i load all the left/right/top/bottom blocks in a function `blocks($side) { .....`

`blocks('l') blocks('r') blocks('c') blocks('d')`

I need a way to tell TWIG how to render, if one of the 4 templates above also contain the `$topBlocks` and/or the `$bottomBlock`s content.

By default and not load any of the 4 templates above i render like this:

```
// render template
  echo $template->render(array (
              'title' => $title1,
              'metaDesc' => $metaDesc,
              'metaKeywords' => $metaKeywords,
              'navContent' => $navContent,
              'leftContent' => $leftContent,
              'defaultContent' => $module_content,
              'rightContent' => $rightContent,
              'footerContent' => $copyright
  ));
```

But twig renders in this case also the html for rightContent , even if there isnt any content.

Comment: This: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html  ?

Comment: No sorry, this is not what i meant.i just want to tell TWIG what template it should load.I don't want to tell that within TWIG.

Comment: Well right now in your code, you don't load *any* template at all. Do you actually know how you would load a specific template?

Comment: Stick to the question please.

Comment: Okay, I take that as a no. You find the answer here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html

Comment: $template = $twig->loadTemplate('index.phtml');
 happy now??????

Comment: So now what is your issue then? Take `$result` and change the template based on it. I don't see any issues with that.

Comment: My question is , that i ask here for the best way to handle the result, so i can call the appropriate template.

Comment: i managed to load 4 base templates, i come to conclusion in my situation and because of the html-template itself there is no other way.I'm ok with that , just need to figure out now how to tell if page has blocksTop and/or blocksBottom to load that into Twig's one of four templates.

Comment: have you seen that twig has a module for *layouts*? It sounds to me a bit what you have here are different layouts.

Comment: yes i came to conclusion that my way of scripting + the bootstrap template i use (Verso) requires to create 4 base layouts.But withing these 4 base layouts i need a way to also add topBlock/bottomBlock, whenever my script tells it excist, to load that into either one of the four base layouts.Beside you inform me of the module layouts.it is more important for me to solve the main problem.

Comment: Yes I see. Well the very first links provides some different various ways to do more dynamic stuff with twig so I normally find it adviseable to read top to bottom. maybe some of the expressions and techniques outlined in it (the cookbook) inspire you to achieve your goals.

Comment: i think i need to put my eye on the `extend` and the `parent` functions. but for the `parent` i need to do a check if i sended within the `$template->render(array`  also a `topBlock` and ore a `bottomBlock`.Dont now how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by start creating 4 default templates.

1. default content only
2. left content with default content
3. left content with default content and right content
4. default content with right content

The way i solve the problem for the top and bottom content is that i simply added the related vars
to the default content, like:

`$moduleContent = $topContent . $module_content . $bottomContent; //self explaining no?`

I want to share my code as an example so it might can be used by others:

```
//generate template variables
$title1 = "This site is powered by smarty";
$metaDesc = "this is the coolest site on the net";
$metaKeywords = "cool,site,internet,number one,ever,created with smarty";

$module_content = $getContent['module_content']; 

$leftContent = blocks2('left');
$rightContent = blocks2('right');
$topContent = blocks2('c');
$bottomContent = blocks2('d');
$footerContent = $copyright;

//name the blockpositions (can be extended but requires hardcoding: $sliderBlock $headerBlock, $addsBlock etc etc)
$leftBlock ='l';
$rightBlock ='r';
$topBlock = 'c';
$bottomBlock = 'd';

$blockposition = array();

$result2 = $db->sql_query("SELECT bposition FROM {$prefix}_blocks_manager WHERE module_title ='$name'"); 
while($row2 = $db->sql_fetchrow($result2)) { 
$blockposition[] = $row2['bposition'];
}

//remove duplicates becouse db output can be like:lllrrrd
$blockposition = array_unique($blockposition);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///We go check if there are top or bottom blocks are active////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//We go add top blocks before module content and bottom blocks after module content
if (in_array($topBlock, $blockposition) AND in_array($bottomBlock, $blockposition)) {
$moduleContent = $topContent . $module_content . $bottomContent;
}
//We go add top blocks before module content
if (in_array($topBlock, $blockposition) AND !in_array($bottomBlock, $blockposition)) {
$moduleContent = $topContent . $module_content;
}
//We go add bottom blocks after module content
if (!in_array($topBlock, $blockposition) AND in_array($bottomBlock, $blockposition)) {
$moduleContent = $module_content . $bottomContent;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// We go check if we need left blocks and/or right blocks or no blocks at all. ////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//We go use a template with left and right blocks
if (in_array($leftBlock, $blockposition) AND in_array($rightBlock, $blockposition)) {
echo $twig->render('left_right.phtml', array('title' => $title1,'metaDesc' => $metaDesc,'metaKeywords' => $metaKeywords,'navContent' => $navContent,'leftContent' => $leftContent,'defaultContent' => $moduleContent,'rightContent' => $rightContent,'footerContent' => $copyright));
}
//We go use a template with just left blocks
if (in_array($leftBlock, $blockposition) AND !in_array($rightBlock, $blockposition)) {
echo $twig->render('left.phtml', array('title' => $title1,'metaDesc' => $metaDesc,'metaKeywords' => $metaKeywords,'navContent' => $navContent,'leftContent' => $leftContent,'defaultContent' => $moduleContent,'footerContent' => $copyright));
}
//We go use a template with just right blocks
if (!in_array($leftBlock, $blockposition) AND in_array($rightBlock, $blockposition)) {
echo $twig->render('right.phtml', array('title' => $title1,'metaDesc' => $metaDesc,'metaKeywords' => $metaKeywords,'navContent' => $navContent,'defaultContent' => $moduleContent,'rightContent' => $rightContent,'footerContent' => $copyright));
}
//We go use a template with just content
if (!in_array($leftBlock, $blockposition) AND !in_array($rightBlock, $blockposition)) {
echo $twig->render('content.phtml', array('title' => $title1,'metaDesc' => $metaDesc,'metaKeywords' => $metaKeywords,'navContent' => $navContent,'defaultContent' => $moduleContent,'footerContent' => $copyright));
}
```